# Wrapping data with <Bytes> when validating signatures

Tags: signatures

So it looks like it is necessary to wrap a signed payload with "<Bytes>" "</Bytes>" before verifying its signature.

Some examples I have found are:

[Offchain signature validation in NFTS pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6e0059a416a5768e58765a49b33c21920c0b0eb9/frame/nfts/src/common_functions.rs#L34-L56)

Where it even shows the following comment

```
// NOTE: for security reasons modern UIs implicitly wrap the data requested to sign into
// <Bytes></Bytes>, that's why we support both wrapped and raw versions.
```

Again, the same wrapping found [here](https://github.com/LibertyDSNP/frequency/blob/b4abdf037ff4d49ae289b018f9c865a2b2b0ce12/common/primitives/src/utils.rs#L100-L110)

So my questions is, where can I find some documentation about this, or some historic explanation of why we need to do this ?. I get that this is how it has to be done, but I have not been able to find anything more about it.

Thanks for any answer beforehand!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't wrap it with `<Bytes> </Bytes>`, a dapp could ask a user to sign a legit transaction instead of a random harmless payload.

In Ethereum, wallets that support the EIP-1271 standard will display the actual payload the user would need to sign.
Without that standard, the only thing user will see is just the hex string.

So, wrapping with `<Bytes> </Bytes>` acts as a simple solution to avoid blind signing of forged transactions.

Comment: This is amazing info, very helpful! Do you have a link to any docs for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. Discovered this while going through various repositories.