# Why are payloads wrapped in a <Bytes> tag?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot-js-extension, signing, apps, signatures

In Polkadot JS Apps, when signing a payload the payload is wrapped in a `<Bytes>` tag. E.g.

[image: screenshot of polkadot js apps]

I put a few console log's in the polkadot JS apps code to figure out what's going on. As you can see, the payload data is `hello` and this gets wrapped before signing. The wrapper is the ASCII chars, e.g.

```
[60, 66, 121, 116, 101, 115, 62, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 60, 47, 66, 121, 116, 101, 115, 62]
```

maps to

```
<Bytes>hello</Bytes>
```

This process of wrapping the `Bytes` tag is done ahead of signing a message / payload.

Is this some kind of convention? Why is this done and what does it achieve?

Comment: See https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/8976/380